# Rest API. Post content

Tags: rest-api

Good afternoon everyone.

I have a website made with wordpress version 5.02.
I want to use Rest Api functionality for developing native android application.
At this address
https://my-site/wp-json I receive a response with all endpoints available in Worpress Rest API.

I am interesting in getting post content by this url.
https://my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/4982
By this url I receive post info. By key "content", "rendered" I can get the post page in html format.

```
{
  "id": 4982,
  "date": "2018-03-18T17:26:46",
  "date_gmt": "2018-03-18T14:26:46",
  "modified": "2018-03-18T17:26:46",
  "modified_gmt": "2018-03-18T14:26:46",
  "slug": "relefnoe-telo",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "post",
  "content": {
    "rendered": " html page here",
    "protected": false
  }}
```

I want to put the post info to my appication natively. Could you tell me please can I get post content in
json format like this:

```
{
  content: {
    "title": "article title",
    "image": "https://image.url",
    "gallery": [
      {
        "url": "https://image.url"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://image.url"
      }
    ],
    "descr": "description"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the data from a WordPress install that you have control over?

Comment: @birgire. Thanks for response. I have control over the data. Could you help me?

Comment: Have you looked into [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) for your custom route ? This could also be a job for graphql?